# How to transfer an object p2p via internet using WCF C#

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

How to transfer an object p2p via internet using WCF C#?

I have an .NET desktop application which is running on 2 different computers which are located in different countries . But now I want to transfer a object from one application to another using WCF .

is there any way to transfer an object from one application to another application via internet using WCF C#

I mean, for that where should I host the WCF service and is this done by WCF callback service?

Comment: You might consider replacing your keyboard!

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc297274.aspx) is a pretty detailed article on using Peer-to-Peer programming with wcf and .NET Framework 3.5.

With a little work you could probably tie a SignalR client into your Winforms app. I have never tried to wire up a signal R client in a library. SignalR was designed for p2p and it may offer more functionality depending on your requirements.

Comment: I like the idea of using SignalR ... otherwise you will have to figure quite a few firewall challenges. SignalR, or any other man-in-the-middle service over HTTP, will let you bypass those complexities.